# Extract file name from read_csv - Python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a script that current reads raw data from a .csv file and performs some pandas data analysis against the data.  Currently the .csv file is hardcoded and is read in like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep="|", names=col)
```

I want to change 2 things:

1. I want to turn this into a loop so it loops through a directory of .csv files and executes the pandas analysis below each one in the script.
2. I want to take each .csv file and strip the '.csv' and store that in a another list variable, let's call it 'new_table_list'.

I think I need something like below, at least for the 1st point(though I know this isn't completely correct). I am not sure how to address the 2nd point

Any help is appreciated

```
import os 

path = '\test\test\csvfiles'
table_list = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        table_list.append(file)
data = pd.read_csv(table_list,sep="|", names=col)
```

Comment: You need to use `os.path.join(path, filename)` to get the full name of the file to read from

Comment: The first argument to `read_csv` needs to be a filename, not a list of filenames.

Comment: @Barmar  Ah, ok.  So read_csv can't take a parameter?  Has to be a single filename?  Ok, I will need to change my approach I think.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, it takes a parameter. That parameter must be a filename or an already open file object that it can read from.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying for that specific variable not to strip the .csv out of the filename.  That makes sense.  The strip variable part was for another purpose entirely, to create a list of files(without .csv).  I think I understand

Comment: I'm not talking about stripping at all. I'm talking about `pd.read_csv(table_list,sep="|", names=col)` You can't use `table_list` as the argument, it's a list, not a filename.

Comment: `read_csv` can only read one CSV file at a time, not all the files in `table_list`.

Comment: got it, thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many ways to do it

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        table_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename,sep="|"))
        new_table_list.append(filename.split(".")[0])
```

One more

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        table_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename,sep="|"))
        new_table_list.append(filename[:-4])
```

and many more

As @barmar pointed out, better to append path as well to the `table_list` to avoid any issues related to path and location of files and script.

Comment: What is the `file` in `table_list.append(file)`? Surely you want to append something useful like `pd.read_csv(pathname, sep='|', names=col)`` somewhere, rather than just two different versions of the filename to two different lists?

Comment: @abarnert yup, that makes much more sense. Though I was trying to solve just second part. Will edit. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
import glob

data = {}
for filename in glob.glob('/path/to/csvfiles/*.csv'):
    data[filename[:-4]] = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="|", names=col)
```

Then `data.keys()` is the list of filenames without the ".csv" part and `data.values()` is a list with one pandas dataframe for each file.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start with using `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path
```

And then leverage the `stem` attribute and `glob` method.

Let's make an import function.

```
def read_csv(f):
    return pd.read_csv(table_list, sep="|")
```

The most generic approach would be to store in a dictionary.

```
p = Path('\test\test\csvfiles')
dod = {f.stem: read_csv(f) for f in p.glob('*.csv')}
```

And you can also use `pd.concat` to turn that into a dataframe.

```
df = pd.concat(dod)
```

Answer (score 2):

to get the list CSV files in the directory use `glob` it is easier than `os`

```
from glob import glob 

# csvs will contain all CSV files names ends with .csv in a list
csvs = glob('you\\dir\\to\\csvs_folder\\*.csv')

# remove the trailing .csv from CSV files names
new_table_list = [csv[:-3] for csv in csvs]

# read csvs as dataframes
dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv, sep="|", names=col) for csv in csvs]

#concatenate all dataframes into a single dataframe
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You may want to double the backslashes, use a raw string or replace them with forward slashes (most libraries work with forward-slash paths even if the path separator for the current OS is a back-slash). In your example, the `\to` in the literal will be interpreted as `0x09o`

Comment: yeah I forgot them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try so:

```
import os
path = 'your path'
all_csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
for f in all_csv_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, f), sep="|", names=col)

# list without .csv
files = [f[:-4] for f all_csv_files]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (at the moment of opening) add the filename to a Dataframe attribute as follow:

```
 ds.attrs['filename']='filename.csv'
```

You can subsequently query the dataframe for the name

```
 ds.attrs['filename']
'filename.csv'
```